# What can I deduce about $f(x)$ if $f$ is balanced or constant?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, mathematics

$\newcommand{\qr}[1]{|#1\rangle}$Question.  Can you check whether this is correct?  Also, given the analysis below, what is the domain of and co-domain of $f(\qr{x})$?  I think it is $V^4 \to W^4 : f$ because

$$\qr{00} = \qr{0}\otimes\qr{0} = \left[\begin{matrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right].$$

Analysis.  Let

$$\qr{x} = a_{00}\qr{00} + a_{01}\qr{01} + a_{10}\qr{10} + a_{11}\qr{11}$$

and let $U_f$ implement some constant or balanced function $f(x)$. Then I claim the following holds given the linear function nature of $U_f$.
\begin{align*}
  f(\qr{x}) &= U_f\qr{x}\\
  &= U_f(a_{00}\qr{00} + a_{01}\qr{01} + a_{10}\qr{10} + a_{11}\qr{11})\\
  &= U_f(a_{00}\qr{00}) + U_f(a_{01}\qr{01}) + U_f(a_{10}\qr{10}) + U_f(a_{11}\qr{11})\\
  &= a_{00}U_f(\qr{00}) + a_{01}U_f(\qr{01}) + a_{10}U_f(\qr{10}) + a_{11}U_f(\qr{11}),
\end{align*}

Now if $f$ is constant --- with $f(\qr{x}) = \qr{00}$ for all $\qr{x}$ ---, then we would have

\begin{align*}
  f(\qr{x}) &= a_{00}U_f(\qr{00}) + a_{01}U_f(\qr{01}) + a_{10}U_f(\qr{10}) + a_{11}U_f(\qr{11})\\
  &= a_{00}\qr{00} + a_{01}\qr{00} + a_{10}\qr{00} + a_{11}\qr{00}\\
  &= (a_{00} + a_{01} + a_{10} + a_{11})\qr{00}.
\end{align*}

If, on the other hand, $f$ is balanced then with probability $1/2$, we have
\begin{align*}
  f(\qr{x}) &= a_{00}U_f(\qr{00}) + a_{01}U_f(\qr{01}) + a_{10}U_f(\qr{10}) + a_{11}U_f(\qr{11})\\
  &= (a_{00} + a_{01} + a_{10} + a_{11})\qr{00}
\end{align*}
and with probability $1/2$ as well

\begin{align*}
  f(\qr{x}) &= a_{00}U_f(\qr{00}) + a_{01}U_f(\qr{01}) + a_{10}U_f(\qr{10}) + a_{11}U_f(\qr{11})\\
  &= (a_{00} + a_{01} + a_{10} + a_{11})\qr{11}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Could you please provide more context to the question? It looks like a homework problem as it is currently written.

Comment: It's not homework.  But even if it was, I think I'm looking to get some clarity here and that seems reasonable.  Would you want to know what I'm doing?  I'm trying to understand Deustch's algorithm and I'm reading [these notes I found on the web](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~sgharibian/courses/CMSC491/notes/Lecture%206%20-%20Deutsch's%20algorithm.pdf).  Take a look at the first exercise.  The exercise is given right after saying that operators are linear.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Of relevance perhaps: [What to do about homework questions](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194/homework-questions-and-what-to-do-about-them).

Comment: Notational nitpick: don't use $U$ for something you don't intend to be unitary.

Comment: @AHusain Interesting.  Thanks.  But, look, [they](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~sgharibian/courses/CMSC491/notes/Lecture%206%20-%20Deutsch's%20algorithm.pdf) are using it.  In these notes, $U_f$ is just a circuit that implements $f$.  But very interesting comment.  That circuit need not be unitary and such nitpick had not even occurred to me yet.  So, thanks.

Comment: @AHusain Hm, I take back back.  I think [all operators must be unitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_(physics)).  (See Unitary operator.)

Comment: @R.Chopin operators do not need to be unitary. Notable examples are the operators describing the result of a measurement.

Comment: @gIS Besides measurement, can you name another one?

Answer (score 2):

$f$ being balanced does not mean that it gives one output with probability $0.5$ and the other output with probability $0.5$.
Instead, it means that half of the inputs are sent to one output and the other half to a different output.

I don't know what you are referring to in the notes you link, but $f$ is there defined as $f:\{0,1\}^n\mapsto\{0,1\}$, and if it is balanced then it will act for example as
$f(00)=f(01)=0$, $f(10)=f(11)=1$.
This is totally different from what you wrote, as you will get something like
$$|x\rangle\mapsto|f(x)\rangle=(a_{00}+a_{01})|0\rangle+(a_{10}+a_{11})|1\rangle.$$

Comment: @gIs I don't follow you.  Are you saying the distribution of (input, output) is not uniform, that being the sole reason the probability of 1 or 0 not being 1/2?

Comment: @gIS I didn't refer to anything in the notes.  (It was only background information to someone who requested.)  So my $f$ is not that $f$.  That $f$ works with a $n$ q-bits, while my $f$ works with 2.  Can you point which line is a wrong deduction in my calculations?  (Or can you show why yours is correct?)  Thank you.

Comment: I referred to the notes because otherwise I don't see how your way of defining a "balanced $f$" makes sense. It is just not the way it is defined in this context. If you don't want to use known notation you have to *define* what are domain and co-domain of $f$, you cannot *ask* for it. If you are just defining your objects as in your post, then I don't understand what is the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that $U_f$ as you've defined it is not unitary. To see this, note that  the overlaps between states are preserved under the action of a unitary: $\langle\psi|\phi\rangle=\langle\psi|U^\dagger U|\phi\rangle$, while for a constant function $f$ you have $U_f|x\rangle=U_f|x'\rangle$ even if $x\neq x'$ (thereby changing the overlap from 0 to 1).

The way that you set this up as a unitary is with some additional qubits. If $f:x\mapsto y$ where $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ and $y\in\{0,1\}^m$, then you define $U_f|x\rangle|y\rangle=|x\rangle|y\oplus f(x)\rangle$. This is definitely unitary because
$$
U_fU_f|x\rangle|y\rangle=|x\rangle|y\oplus f(x)\oplus f(x)\rangle=|x\rangle|y\rangle,
$$
so $U_f$ is its own inverse.

Of course, you could define a quantum operation that always sets everything to 0. It's basically a measurement (in the $Z$ basis) followed by a compensating action depending on the measurement outcome. But then you can't use linearity as you did in your analysis, because you have to follow through the different measurement outcomes separately.